# BootStrap DropMenu Not Working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a dropdown menu but it is not working:

```
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
            <ul id="hld" style="margin-top:10px;">
                                    <li class="dropdown" style="border:1px solid #333;padding:5px;text-align:center;">
                <a href="/a/home.html" class="dropdown-toggle">Menu</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="/cat/b.html">Tom</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/cat/c.html">Greg</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/cat/d.html">Jane</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </li>
                           </ul>
                           </div>
```

I am using Bootstrap [CSS](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) framework and have included all the appropriate CSS and JS files. What am I doing wrong? While looking at other questions similar to mines, I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: You have HTML errors...try validating that first.

Comment: >_< Sorry for the typos. I fixed them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing some key elements.

This is what your dropdown element should look like.

```
 <li class="dropdown" style="border:1px solid #333;padding:5px;text-align:center;">
```

This goes with the dropdown-toggle class.

```
data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
  <ul id="hld" style="margin-top:10px;">
    <li class="dropdown" style="border:1px solid #333;padding:5px;text-align:center;"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Menu <span class="caret"></span></a>

      <ul class="dropdown-menu ">
        <li><a href="/cat/b.html ">Tom</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="/cat/c.html ">Greg</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="/cat/d.html ">Jane</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution may be that you are not referencing the jquery.js source **before** bootstrap.js source

Answer (score 0):

First mistake was a couple of quotation marks missing. On top of that, you are not following the syntax and classes listed here: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns

Here is the correct version:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Menu
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul id="hld" class="dropdown-menu" style="margin-top:10px;">
    <li><a href="/cat/b.html">Tom</a></li>
    <li><a href="/cat/c.html">Greg</a></li>
    <li><a href="/cat/d.html">Jane</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```